# How can I make a POST retrofit request with a List of Object in parameter?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

i want to do a Post request with retrofit but I get error 500 internal server and I don't know why. The request is working fine on Postman.
The parameter is a list of Object :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("insertTripsAndroid")
    Call<ResponseBody> insertTripsAndroid(@Field("trips_") List<TrajectJsonToPush> trips_);
```

The Json expected in parameter is like this :

```
[{"is_completed":true,
"date_time_start":"20:10:2019-01:22:41",
"time_start":1571527361,"speed_mean":0,
"time_end":1571527450,"location_end_id":67,
"user_id":72,"location_start_id":1,
"number_of_locations":67,
"trip_id":123,"speed_max":0,
"time_duration":89,"motif":"Inconnus",
"mode":"Inconnus","distance":3227.5005757874319,
"date_time_end":"20:10:2019-01:24:10"}
]
```

Here is my class TrajectJsonToPush :

```
public class TrajectJsonToPush {
    int trip_id;
    int user_id;
    int location_start_id;
    int location_end_id;
    int time_start;
    String date_time_start;
    int time_end;
    String date_time_end;
    int time_duration;
    int number_of_locations;
    double distance;
    double speed_mean;
    double speed_max;
    boolean is_completed;
    String motif;
    String mode;

    public TrajectJsonToPush(int trip_id, int user_id, int location_start_id, int location_end_id, int time_start, String date_time_start, int time_end, String date_time_end, int time_duration, int number_of_locations, double distance, double speed_mean, double speed_max, boolean is_completed, String motif, String mode) {
        this.trip_id = trip_id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.location_start_id = location_start_id;
        this.location_end_id = location_end_id;
        this.time_start = time_start;
        this.date_time_start = date_time_start;
        this.time_end = time_end;
        this.date_time_end = date_time_end;
        this.time_duration = time_duration;
        this.number_of_locations = number_of_locations;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.speed_mean = speed_mean;
        this.speed_max = speed_max;
        this.is_completed = is_completed;
        this.motif = motif;
        this.mode = mode;
    }
}
```

So my question is why do I get error 500 internal server ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using proguard? Try annotating your model with @SerializedName("speed_max") for every parameter.

Comment: It's still not working with the annotation. And no I am not using ProGuard

Comment: In my opinion the problem come from retrofit who don't know that he have to parse my list of object into Json, but I don't know how to fix it